# Translate english sentences to ALC description logic

Tags: description-logic

I have the following two English sentences:

1. Mary is a Person.
2. Bulldog is a specie of dog. French bulldog is a specie of bulldog.
3. The only kind of dog that Mary owns is French bulldog.

I would like to know which of the following ways is the correct way to translate the third and the sentences based on the knowledge given.

**1st approach**

```
Bulldog ⊆ Dog 
FrenchBulldog ⊆ Bulldog
FrenchBulldog ⊆ Dog

(∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⨅ Person)(MARY)
```

**2nd approach**

```
∀owns.Bulldog ⊆ ∀owns.Dog 
∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⊆ ∀owns.Bulldog

(¬(∀owns.Dog⊔Bulldog) ⨅ ∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⨅ Person)(MARY) (*)
```

**3rd approach**

```
Bulldog ⊆ Dog 
FrenchBulldog ⊆ Bulldog

(Person⨅(∀owns.FrenchBulldog⨅(∀owns.¬Dog⊔∀owns.¬Bulldog)))(MARY) (**)
```

I know that the first approach is correct. But I would like to re-written the third English sentence as approaches 2-(*), 3-(**).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach 1 is correct and approaches 2 and 3 are incorrect.

I assume with

```
(¬(∀owns.(Dog⊔Bulldog)) ⨅ ∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⨅ Person)(MARY)
```

by adding `(¬(∀owns.(Dog⊔Bulldog))` you trying to ensure Mary only owns `FrenchBulldog`s, but it is achieving the opposite.

```
(¬(∀owns.(Dog⊔Bulldog)) ≡ ∃owns.¬(Dog⊔Bulldog) ≡ ∃owns.(¬Dog ⨅ ¬Bulldog)
```

Thus in essence you are saying that Mary owns only French bulldogs (`∀owns.FrenchBulldog`) AND you are saying she owns at least 1 thing that is not a dog and not a bulldog (`∃owns.(¬Dog ⨅ ¬Bulldog)`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Henriette. Is there any way to achieve the same result as approach 1 but with approach 3? ```∀owns.FrenchBulldog⨅(∀owns.¬Dog⨅∀owns.¬Bulldog))``` Doesn't it transale that Mary owns only FrenchBulldong and not any other Dog or Bulldog?

Comment: No. ∀owns.¬Dog means everything Mary owns is not a Dog. It does NOT mean " not any other dog".

Comment: BTW. To approach 1 you want add `∃owns.FrenchBulldog`. That is you want `(∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⨅ ∃owns.FrenchBulldog ⨅ Person)(MARY). This is to ensure Mary owns at least 1 French bulldog. Otherwise she may have 0 French bulldog.

Comment: Thanks for the note on approach 1. Let's does infer that no more than 1 dog can be owned in this knowledge base. So everyone owns only 1 dog. If I want to achieve as you said "not any other dog" how approach 3 should be written? Is there a way?

Comment: Also in your answer you have this ```(¬(∀owns.(Dog⊔Bulldog)) ≡ ∃owns.¬(Dog⊔Bulldog) ≡ ∃owns.(¬Dog ⨅ ¬Bulldog)```... if we knew that she could own only 1 Dog (of any specie) and no more (take it as we knew)..could your answer be written as ```(∀owns.FrenchBulldog⨅ ∃owns.(¬Dog ⨅ ¬Bulldog))(MARY)```

Comment: No. Approach 3 cannot be rewritten.

Comment: Ok. As far as this (1)```∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⊆ ∀owns.Bulldog``` =>This translates to _For everyone that owns a FrenchBulldog those dogs are Bulldogs_ ... (2)```∃owns.FrenchBulldog ⊆ ∀owns.Bulldog``` =>This translates to _At least one that owns a FrenchBulldog that dog must be Bulldog_ ... (3) ```∀owns.FrenchBulldog ⊆ ∃owns.Bulldog``` => This translates to _For everyone that owns a FrenchBulldog that dog should be Bulldog for at least one of them_ ...It this correct?

Comment: None of the semantics you given for (1)-(3) is correct. This is too much to deal with in comments. I have answered your original question. You can read more about universal  and existential property restrictions on my blog, [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/category/semantic-technologies/owl/universal-property-restrictions/) and [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/category/semantic-technologies/owl/existential-property-restrictions/).